# Adapter getView is called multiple times

Tags: android, listview

My getView is called multiple times. I set fill_parent width and fill_parent height of listview, but it doesn't work.
See the code of adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
private Context ctx;
public ArrayList<Objects> listToSend;
private ViewHolder holder;
private TextView tv;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;


public AdapterOrderType(Context context, ArrayList<Objects> list) {
    this.ctx = context;
    this.listToSend = list;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return  listToSend.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listToSend.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView tv;
    private LinearLayout ll;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Object object = objects.get(position);

     ViewHolder holder = null;
     if (convertView == null) {
         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_objects, null);
         holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.objname);

         convertView.setTag(holder);
     } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
     }
    Log.e("called times: ",String.valueOf(position)); 
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
//  }
  }
```

My Log:

called times: 0

called times: 1

called times: 2

called times: 0

---

My adapter is drawing wrong number of listview items and it's problem

[image]

Comment: that is a pretty normal behavior...

Comment: @WarrenFaith but size of my list is 3.Why i need another position again?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618272/custom-listview-adapter-getview-method-being-called-multiple-times-and-in-no-co

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376708/getview-called-multiple-times-in-android

Comment: There solution is fill_parent of listview. It not works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it will be. The `getView` method in adapter is called for each row in the List that is visible on screen so it will obviously be called multiple times.