# GetView Called Multiple times

Tags: android, gridview, getview

I have seen several other questions regarding GetView being called in an adapter several times and causing performance issues. However, this question is not a duplicate.

All of the answers I have found mention that having a **ListView** with a height of *wrap_content* will cause such behavior, but I am using an adapter to populate a **GridView**, with the height set to *match_parent*. GetView is called over and over until the activity crashes.

Here is the layout with the GridView I am trying to populate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.jeff_fennell.capstone.GroupDetailView"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/members_in_group"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:id="@+id/group_detail_name"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/invite_member_button"
                android:text="@string/invite_friends_button"
                android:onClick="openInviteDialog"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/group_empty_message"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:text="@string/group_empty_message"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>
        <it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:id="@+id/members_in_group"
            android:layout_weight="0">
        </it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/albums"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:id="@+id/group_albums"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/new_album_button"
                android:text="@string/new_album_button_text"
                android:onClick="openCreateAlbumDialog"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:id="@+id/album_list">
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the adapter:

```
public class AlbumAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Album>{
        private Activity activity;

        public AlbumAdapter(Activity activity, List<Album> albums) {
            super(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.album_preview, albums);
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Album album = getItem(position);
            RelativeLayout albumView = null;

            if (convertView != null) {
                albumView = (RelativeLayout)convertView;
            } else {
                albumView = (RelativeLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.album_preview, null);
            }

            TextView albumName = (TextView)albumView.findViewById(R.id.album_name);
            albumName.setText(album.getName());

            Call<List<Image>> getAlbumPreview = Utils.getClient()
                .getAlbumPreviewImages(
                    album.getGroupId(),
                    album.getAlbumId(),
                    UserProfile.getAuthenticationToken(activity)
                );

            getAlbumPreview.enqueue(new Callback<List<Image>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<Image>> call, Response<List<Image>> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<Image> previewImages = response.body();
                        for (int i = 0; i < previewImages.size(); i++) {
                            Image image = previewImages.get(i);
                            int[] imageViewsToPopulate = {
                                R.id.image_1,
                                R.id.image_2,
                                R.id.image_3,
                                R.id.image_4,
                                R.id.image_5
                            };
                            final ImageView previewImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(imageViewsToPopulate[i]);
                            Glide
                                .with(activity)
                                .load(image.getUrl())
                                .asBitmap()
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_people_white_48dp)
                                .centerCrop()
                                .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(previewImageView) {
                                    @Override
                                    protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                                        RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                                                RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(activity.getResources(), resource);
                                        circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                                        previewImageView.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                                    }
                                });
                        }
                    } else {
                        //set no images message
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<Image>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
            return albumView;
        }
```

I realize I have some hard-coded values, and the code needs to be cleaned up a little, but I just haven't gotten around to cleanup/refactoring yet.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/18377020/3981656

Comment: fill_parent has been deprecated since API level 8

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ViewHolder pattern.
Example of implementation:
https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: I implemented a ViewHolder pattern and it fixed the problem. I appreciate the help.